# What boardgame comes closest to the computer game Frozen Synapse?

Tags: board-game-adaptations

According to what I've read about [Gunslinger](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1044/gunslinger) it looks like both share similar game mechanics, but not having played this 1982 game I'm not sure. Does it come close to [Frozen Synapse](http://videogamegeek.com/videogame/87713/frozen-synapse) ? Or is there another game that is even closer?

Update to be more specific:

First, *Frozen Synapse* is my favorite PC game. So I like all of the elements of this game that I try to describe in the following, and I am looking for a boardgame that has as many of those elements as possible.

In Frozen Synapse I plan the movement of my guys for the next 5 seconds. On the 2-dimensional map I can program them to turn or move or hold still. They each have an individual view of sight. When they see an enemy they first aim then shoot. The time it takes for them to aim then shoot and the chances to hit depends upon:

1. their weapon, shotgun being faster than machine gun being faster than sniper rifle, while Sniper rifle has higher chances to hit than machine gun, and shotgun has the shortest range.
2. wheather they are moving or holding still
3. whether they are behind covering objects

If two enemy guys happen to see each other at the exact same time, the guy not moving with the faster gun is the killer (no hitpoints - one successful hit means a kill). So there is no luck involved but the winner of a fight is clearly defined taking into account the above factors. Each player plans the actions of their guys simultaniously not knowing what the opponent player might do. The players may test-execute their planned actions. They may even test-plan and test-execute the actions of their opponent to see what would be the outcome altogether. After the players have finished their planning phase their "programs" are executed simultaneously: the guys do their planned movement and fire fights are resolved.

I'm looking for a game that:

- offers similar tactics, like which guy with what gun goes where, who covers whom, when to move which guy and when to let them hold still
- no luck involvement but a clearly defined action and event resolution like in 1., 2., 3. above
- has "fog of war" and individual character sight
- has secret planning and then simultaneous execution

*Gunslinger* seems to be about planning the actions of a cowboy during a shooting in a saloon. It's key to be fast. The players plan the actions in a "split second".

Comment: Can you be more specific? From a quick look at that VGG link, it looks like Frozen Synapse is about simultaneous move resolution in a tactical based arena kind of situation? What specifically are you looking for in a "similar" game, and why does Gunslinger sound like it might be it?

Comment: Since this doesn't really answer your question I'll post this as a comment: you might want to take a look at the X-Wing boardgame, which uses a similar secret move technique, but misses several of your desired attributes.

Comment: Do you mean [star-wars-x-wing-miniatures-game][1]? [1]: http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/103885/star-wars-x-wing-miniatures-game

Comment: That's the one!

Comment: @Stonecrusher Just fyi, link syntax in comments is done `[like this](http://example.com/)` - skip the [1] definition stuff, that only works in answers and questions. :)

Comment: Boardgamegeek lets you search by tags, which might help you find something, but you have a long list of demands there. :) Robo Rally might be worth looking into. It doesn't really have the combat elements you're talking about, but it does have the simultaneous planning followed by locked-in execution bit, and it's pretty fun.

Comment: [VOLT](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/211454/volt) comes rather close to what I've bee looking for, because it offers 3 of the 4 criteria I mentioned in my posting.